# Disable custom dates in jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to disable certain dates from a Jquery UI datepicker calendar.

My problem is that only the last date checked by disableDays function is disabled, not all of them. Why it disables only the last checked date. Should I return a different response from this function ?

Full script:

```
var disabled_days = new Array(); // Array of Date() objects


$('.date-picker-day').live('click', function () {
    $(this).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd',
        beforeShow: function () {
            [..]
        },
        beforeShowDay: disableDays,
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {

        }

    }).focus();
});

function disableDays(date) {
    var ret = false;
    $.each(disabled_days, function (k, v) {
        if (v.getDate() == date.getDate()) {
            console.log(v + 'vs.' + date + ' invalid');
            ret = [false];
        } else {
            ret = [true];
        }
    });

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop further iterations of the `disabled_days` array as soon as a negative match is found, else in the next value iteration the date will not match and `ret` will again get `true` value

```
function disableDays(date) {
    var ret = false;
    $.each(disabled_days, function (k, v) {
        if (v.getDate() == date.getDate()) {
            console.log(v + 'vs.' + date + ' invalid');
            ret = [false];
            return false;
        } else {
            ret = [true];
        }
    });
    return ret;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FZMP9/)

Comment: Thank you very much! I am amazed I haven't compiled that in my head.